# Can't update with an $or and multiple $exists

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I try to update the whole collection to set a value in a field; who can be empty or not exists.

Here is my request :

```
db.noa_drafts.updateMany(
{
    $or : [
        {"InsuranceAgreement":{$exists:false}},
        {"InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct":{$exists:false}},
        {"InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct":null},
        {"InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct.productVersion":{$exists:false}},
        {"InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct.productVersion":null},
        {"InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct.productVersion":""}
    ]
},
{$set:{"InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct.productVersion":"1.0"}}
)
```

I have the following error message :

> "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (isBasedOnProduct of
>   InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct.productVersion) to traverse the
>   element ({isBasedOnProduct: null})",

I don't exactly understand the error message, and what I have done wrong.

Comment: As I have a check on `Robo 3T` its work well.

Comment: Could you show your schema

Comment: Can you update your question to include an example document that reproduces the problem?

Comment: {$set:{"InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct":{"productVersion":"1.0" } }})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs when *InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct* is null or doesn't exist. An error is thrown when the `$set` references it. As IftekharDani states in a comment, you can get around it by using this:

```
{
  $set:{"InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct":{"productVersion":"1.0"}
}
```

**But**, if *InsuranceAgreement* doesn't exist, you still get an error:

> "cannot use the part (InsuranceAgreement of InsuranceAgreement.isBasedOnProduct) to traverse the element ({InsuranceAgreement: null})"

Handle both cases with the following:

```
{
  $set:{"InsuranceAgreement":{"isBasedOnProduct.productVersion":"1.0"}
}
```